# Canadian citizen, TN worker, commute daily from Canada: am I a US person for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, canada, tn-visa

I only have citizenship of Canada.
I work for a US company on TN Status.
I commute daily from home in Canada to office in US and back.
I do not reside in the US.
I get a W2 and file taxes with the IRS every year.
I have property and equity only in Canada.

My Canadian bank is asking me a question if I am a US person for tax purposes or not?
I believe that I am not a US person for tax purposes.

Can someone advise me on this?

Comment: Would not the *bank* and the *IRS* be the first ones to ask? What value does any answer you get  here have? Would you say when you are audited in 5 years "but I got this answer on money SE from this guy with 14.5k rep that said I'm not!" ??

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think it's safe to assume that since their bank is the one that first asked the question it's a sign they don't know the answer.

Comment: @Logarr They don't know the client's exact circumstances. Given those they may know the answer.

Comment: Get a copy of the instructions attached to the non-resident and partial year resident tax forms.  If it's like it was when I had a TN (quite a while ago), all the rules are there.  As a TN, you are neither a citizen nor a resident alien.  Instead, you are a "temporary, non-resident alien" (https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-aliens).  Remember, you need to pay Canadian taxes on your world wide income - but the tax treaties will keep you from being double-taxed even if you need to pay US taxes (which I suspect you will)

Comment: My first thought when I read the title was, "how does he commute to Tennessee every day???"  :D

Comment: @RonJohn: A `TN` status comes from _Trade NAFTA_.  It's the successor status to what was called `TC` status back in the early 1990s when there was a Canada-US Free Trade Agreement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%E2%80%93United_States_Free_Trade_Agreement) which was replaced by NAFTA a few years later.  TN status has very a very light-weight application mechanism (show up at the border with a passport, some papers and money, fill in a form and presto).  It allows Mexican and Canadian professionals access to work in _temporary_ jobs as non-resident aliens (though they can live in the US)

Answer (score 74):

Basically, you are a US person if you are a US citizen or "resident alien" for tax purposes. You are a resident alien if you pass the Substantial Presence Test or the Green Card Test. Since you don't have a green card, it's just the Substantial Presence Test.

In Publication 519, there is a section on [regular commuters from Canada or Mexico](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2020_publink1000222132). It says that for regular commuters from Canada or Mexico, you do not count the days where you commute to work in the US.

If you exclude the days where you commute to work in the US, you likely do not have enough days of presence in the US to pass the Substantial Presence Test, and therefore I believe you are not a resident alien, and not a US person.

Comment: As a note, if you are still unsure or have reservations about your status, speak with a professional. They will be able to better advise you than anyone on an internet Q&A website.

Comment: @Anoplexian While your comment is accurate, this answer is well-sourced directly to an IRS reference, and it summarizes the data there without stepping outside of the IRS's guidance.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Look, that's great and all, really. I'm not saying this is wrong, but if you're UNCOMFORTABLE about your financial state of being, the people on this site are NOT QUALIFIED or NOT HIRED to provide financial or legal advise. When the alternative could be *breaking the law*, a professional can tell you best. (As a note, I upvoted)

Comment: @Anoplexian I hear you, but I think that caveat could basically apply to any tax question on this site, and of all such answers, I think this one is incredibly direct in its sourcing and conclusion, so I don't think it's so emphatically necessary here compared to elsewhere. The fact that Publication 519 is so directly applicable to OP's exact situation is important in how trustworthy the advice is to someone less sure of their situation.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I agree, but I feel that *because* it's well sourced, it should have the disclaimer, rather than despite it. *If something were to happen* and the OP was unsure, or uncomfortable, or whatnot and *someone else* came across this question and took it as gospel, that could cause some issues.

Comment: @Anoplexian Maybe this is just an industry thing I've grown too used to, but I see the caveats listed there in the answer: "...you *likely* do not have..." and "... therefore *I believe* you are not...". Seems pretty typical.